# Navigating from One form to another

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have  a issue of navigation between forms.Name of my application is SchoolManagement.

1. `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("FormName", UriKind.Relative));`
   when i use this line of code to navigate it shows an error of SchoolManagement does not contain the definition of NavigationService althogu i have added the name space 
   using `System.Windows.Navigation;` in my aplication.
2. `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("formName.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`
   when i use this code it shows object reference is required for non-Static field.
3. `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));`
   and the last code when i use this its connecting to google.com but when i replace it with my form its not navigating to it.

Can anyone please point out the mistake..its an emergency

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The navigation service is different from System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate.  The browser navigation takes you to a new web address.  The Navigation service is specifically for using the Silverlight navigation service to go between pages within your Silverlight app.  Did you create your Silverlight project as a "Silverlight Navigation Application"?  If so then the code should be in place for you to use NavigationService.Navigate as you described.  If not the problem is probably with the code you used to set up the Navigation Service.

Comment: Well, the easiest route is to recreate your app as a "Silverlight Navigation Application" since it will all be set up for you.  However, if that isn't practical for your situation, you will need to make sure you have a "Frame" control (probably in MainPage.xaml).  If you have a reference to the frame control in a variable called frame1 you could navigate by calling the instance method frame1.Navigate(Uri uri).  This uri is interpreted by a UriMapper within the Frame control (if you set one up).  Also, each page that you create to navigate between should inherit from the "Page" control.

Comment: Another important part that I just recalled, is that if you are setting this up manually, you will need to reference System.Windows.Controls.Navigation in your project.  The NavigationService should be accessible from any pages loaded into your Navigation Frame.  This webpage seems to have a good description of the system overall: [link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx)